# Is reading from unallocated memory safe?

Tags: c

Is reading from a random address safe? I know writing is undefined behaviour but how about reading only?

Well, in many visual debuggers, I can see the contents of the memory in an arbitrary address. How is this done?

Comment: no. it's undefined, and probably will cause segfault. it shows, because current page is actually allocated to the process, in the sense of OS.

Comment: No. reading at a random address will most of the time cause a segmentation error,  because it xill be outside the bounds of the segments the operating systems has reserved for the execution of your process.

Comment: A debugger may know more about the underlying system than you can safely assume in C code. Or you might just be getting "lucky". Reading from an arbitrary address *might* happen to "work".

Comment: In the case of Visual Studio, it's debugger usually shows unallocated (not mapped into the virtual address space of a process) memory with "??" instead of data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the behavior is undefined, the answer is undefined - or at the very least, erratic.

If you get lucky and the random address is [within the memory bounds](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_memory_and_heaps.html) of your program, it would be fine to read most likely and you'd just get random junk.

If it's outside of the scope, (i.e. 0x0/NULL), you'd most likely get a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (although again, this isn't guaranteed) which would terminate your program - if you'd consider this "safe" then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: There's no guarantee (in the C language) that accessing an invalid address will cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: How can a program find its "memory bounds"?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not safe.  Even if you don't care about the value being defined or accurate, there is such a thing as memory mapped IO, so a random address could interact with peripheral hardware.  I did that in the days before protected memory, and yes, it can bring down the system.

Nowadays, depending on your system, I'd expect to see a segfault for addresses outside your process space.  Without that protection, a bad app could access valuable data, like passwords, credit card info, etc. when used in a good app.

Also, addresses you see in the debugger are likely not real, physical addresses.  Instead, you probably only see virtual memory addresses.