# Segmentation error, what is missing in my code?

Tags: c

I'm trying to get my code to convert a text file with 3 columns, xcoor, ycoor, and a symbol with 2 characters into a 30x30 map that prints the 2nd character of the symbol with the rest of the spaces being filled with a '.' However, my code doesn't seem to run, and I get a segmentation error when I try inputting the text file, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

```
int main(void)
{
   char grid[30][30];
   for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<30;j++){
         grid[i][j]='.';
      }
   }

   int xcoor,ycoor;
   char symbol[2];
   while((xcoor!=0)||(scanf("%d",&xcoor)))
   {
      while(xcoor==0){
         scanf("%d",&xcoor);
      }
      scanf("%d %c%c",&ycoor,&symbol[0],&symbol[1]);
      grid[xcoor-1][ycoor-1]=symbol[1];
   }

   for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<30;j++){
         printf("%c ",grid[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to use a debugger and look where your code fails. BTW: The code is nearly unreadable. Hard coded numbers the best way o success :-)

Comment: Please add [assertions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/assert) that verify that `xcoor-1` and `ycoor-1` are within the valid range of `[0, 30)`.

Comment: 1)`xcoor` is uninitialize. 2) If there is an invalid input, you need to clear the input buffer  (stdin).

Answer (score 2):

This may not cover ALL of your errors, but immediately I see this:

```
int xcoor,ycoor;
char symbol[2];
while((xcoor!=0)
```

Do you think `xcoor` has a valid value right now? Should it? Because it doesn't. You've created a variable, then before actually setting it to anything, you are checking its value.

It's more than likely your `scanf` call that's giving you trouble. Regardless, try actually setting these variables. It will most likely fix your issues.

See here for more info: [Is reading from unallocated memory safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852028/is-reading-from-unallocated-memory-safe/30852070#30852070)

Answer (score 0):

You are using an uninitialized variable `xcoor` in the conditional of the `while` statement.

You can fix that by initializing `xcoor`.

More importantly, you can simplify the code for reading user data and the related error checks. Here's what I suggest:

```
while ( scanf("%d%d %c%c", &xcoor, &ycoor, &symbol[0], &symbol[1]) == 4 )
{
   if ( xcoor < 0 || xcoor >= 30 )
   {
      // Deal with problem.
      fprintf(stderr, "Out or range value of xcoor: %d\n", xcoor);
      exit(1);
   }
   if ( ycoor < 0 || ycoor >= 30 )
   {
      // Deal with problem.
      fprintf(stderr, "Out or range value of ycoor: %d\n", ycoor);
      exit(1);
   }

   grid[xcoor-1][ycoor-1] = symbol[1];
}
```